# magento2.1 dropdown attribute list.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category-listing, list.phtml

How to get a dropdown attribute value on the category page, i set the show in listing to yes and added this attribute to product. 
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you:

```
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

please let me know if any issue you have

Comment: Also you can use https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258711/how-to-get-dropdown-value-magento2-1 any other answers too.